# Wordpress: HowTo pass persisted/global values from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I have created two pages in wordpress, which both utilise plugins via shortcodes:

`[sc_page1]`
`[sc_page2]`

In the callback function of page1, I have the following code:

```
<?php
function showcountries_callback() {

    include_once("pdo_mysql.php");

    pdo_connect("localhost","wpuser","920support");
    pdo_select_db("wpdb");

    $getIDs = pdo_query("SELECT value from P where id=y");
    echo json_encode($getIDs, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
?>
```

My javascript does the following:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    jQuery('#MyForm').submit(function(){
        jQuery.post('', function() {
            window.location = 'http://192.x.x.x/index.php/searchresults/?id=' + data;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And in the fontend function of page2, I want to do the following:

```
<?php
function searchresults_frontend() {
    foreach($getIDs as $row){
       $htmlSearchResult .= "<option value='{$row[somevalue]}'>{$row[somevalue]}</option>";
    }
    return $htmlSearchResult;

    }
add_shortcode("sr_frontend", "searchresults_frontend");
?>
```

Once the query in page1 is completed, the user is redirected to page2 via `window.location.href`. So how can I use the object value, `$getIDs`, from page1 in page2 as I've described?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, the simplest way to pass data around between pages is to have the first snippet you posted return an hidden field with `value` set to `$getIDs`.

Then, from the javascript snippet you can access the hidden field, read the value it contains and pass it to the second page as a URL parameter, so now you have the value available to the second snippet of code in the $_GET.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, I will give it a try. I was hoping that there was a neater alternative to having to pass objects via urls, for example global variables.

Comment: Ok, so now i've got the url passing to page2 as, http://192.x.x.x/index.php/searchresults/?id=[object 0Object], and $someVar = $_GET("id") holds [object 0Object] as its value. How do I unwrap the object? As can be seen in my javascript I used echo json_encode($getIDs, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), to pass the object back to the javascript. I tried $somevar = json_decode($_GET("id")), and then print_r($somevar), but this displays 1. What am I missing?

Comment: You get [object ...] because you tried to print a json structure as a string. To get a real string you should use `JSON.stringify(data)` instead of `data` when concatenating it to the URL. However, if the id you are passing is just a single number it would be probably better to avoid using json_encode in the first place, and just return the id from the PHP script (in your case it may be something like `$getIDs[0]->value`).